# My first scanf() is not waiting for input but still waits for and accepts input later

Tags: c

I am having an issue with some code for an assignment to familiarize myself with processes and the fork() system call. For some reason when I call scanf() in the initial if statement it isn't waiting for an input right away, first the program proceeds to the next scanf and waits for input there. I know there are many similar quests but I couldn't find one with my exact problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
  pid_t pid;
  int pipeid[2];
  pid = fork();


  if(pid >0){
    int x;
    printf("reading x from user: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("display %d",x);
    wait(0);
  } 
  else{
    int y;
    printf("reading y from user: ");
    scanf(" %d", &y);
    printf("%d",y);
    printf("parent proccess %d created child proccess %d\n", getppid(),getpid());
  }
}
```

output for this program looks like this

```
reading x from user: reading y from user 3
4
4parentproccess (Ppid) created child process (pid)
display 3
```

the first 3 and 4 are user input, so it seems like the program is going straight to the second scanf after it sees the first one? The process ids are always correct.

Comment: Looks to me like there are two different processes calling scanf.  Why would one wait for the other?

Comment: It's working fine. No problem with those 2 processes. For the printing order (if you want to see first printf & scanf and move to the next ones in the parent) you need to wait for the child to finish before doing work on parent.

Answer (score 0):

You're forking the process before calling `scanf`. This gives you 2 processes. Both processes are then calling `scanf`, one reading "x" and the other reading "y". They're both waiting for user input, but because you have two processes both doing it at the same time, you get both messages.